# Destroying a bootstrapped angular2 component

Tags: angular

I've previously worked on projects using Backbone, JQuery, and RequireJS and now exploring Angular2.

I have have an existing SPA that hosts various "widgets" using primarily backbone and have gotten Angular2 components running side by side.

I can load multiple Angular2 components by using the the bootstrap method after importing using requireJs.

The parent element of the angular widgets will be managed using backbone/jquery.

What is the best way to dispose or destroy of angular2 widgets?

From what I understand, the bootstrap method creates a new 'Zone'. Is there a way to force onDestroy for all child components and dispose of the zone?

Answer (score 2):

After digging into the source code, the bootstrap function returns a promise which resolves with the ApplicationRef instance. You can simply call the dispose() method on that object.